# CSS3 slide div on mouseover

Tags: html, css

I want to make a div slide over another backward one, but no idea how to any tips? 
i can make the animation but when i mouse over the animaton dont work properly, can someone explain me why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.fundo_main {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}
.fundo_main:hover {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    -webkit-animation-name:myfirst;
    position:relative;
}
.fundo {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-animation-name:myfirst;
}

.fundo:hover {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    -webkit-animation-name:myfirst;
    -webkit-animation-duration:.3s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-direction:left;

}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0% { width:0px; }
    65% { width: 150px;}    
    100% { width:200px; }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="fundo_main">
    <div class="fundo"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle to explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: It's working fine [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/KUaj9/). What's the problem?

Comment: It's working fine. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: its not, its kinda bugg sometimes when you mouse over, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say change this:

```
.fundo:hover
```

To this one:

```
.fundo_main:hover .fundo
```

Comment: Awesome work like a charm, i kinda (actually a LOT) new to these css3 "new" stuff

Comment: Any tips to a similar mouseout effect?

Comment: Don't put the animation on the `:hover` state if you want to have the mouseout effect as well. See http://www.impressivewebs.com/subtleties-css3-transitions/ (it's about transitions, but the same applies to animations)